Names of Kanya and Kanya puja
Girls of eight, nine and ten years are called Gauri, Rohini and Kanya.

अष्टवर्षा भवेद्गौरी नववर्षा तु रोहिणी ।
दशवर्षा भवेत्कन्या अत ऊर्ध्वं रजस्वला ॥
A girl of eight years is called Gaurī. One of nine years is Rohiṇī. A girl of ten years shall be a Kanyā. Beyond this she is Rajasvalā (one with menses).

#1 Are there any other names for girls aged 5 to 7 or higher?
#2 Add per the above quote, does Kanya puja has to be with ten year olds only? Or under ten is fine as different forms of Ambika?
#3 What is the right age group for kanya puja?
